# How is git checkout implemented?

Tags: git, implementation

When running `git checkout`, the mergebase of the old `HEAD` and the new `HEAD` can be arbitrarily far back. The naïve implementation would be to linearly apply each diff, yet the operation runs instantly.

I have a hunch it might be implemented with something kind of skiplisty for intermediate diff caching, but that's just a guess.

Does anybody know how it's implemented? Thanks! :)

Comment: [You could go to Github and review the source code of Git, y'know...](https://github.com/git/git/search?l=bash&q=checkout)

Comment: git is magic, simple as that :)

Comment: Commits do not store deltas, they store trees.  There's no need to apply diffs: checkout just extracts files.  (Objects stored in pack files may need some delta-decompression, but that's a different story.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a good example on how a checkout is (in principle) implemented in the [javascript implementation of Git (as an exercise) **Gitlet**](http://gitlet.maryrosecook.com/) by **Mary Rose Cook**.

See the [annotated source code](http://gitlet.maryrosecook.com/docs/gitlet.html)

For a **checkout**, the steps are:

> - `checkout()` changes the index, working copy and HEAD to reflect the content of `ref`.
>     `ref` might be a branch name or a commit hash.
> - Get the hash of the commit to check out.
> - Abort if `ref` cannot be found.
> - Abort if the hash to check out points to an object that is a not a commit.
> - Abort if ref is the name of the branch currently checked out. Abort if head is detached, `ref` is a commit hash and `HEAD` is pointing at that hash.
> - Get a list of files changed in the working copy.
>     Get a list of the files that are different in the head commit and the commit to check out.
>     If any files appear in both lists then abort.
> - Otherwise, perform the checkout.
> - If the `ref` is in the objects directory, it must be a hash and so this checkout is detaching the head.
> - Get the list of differences between the current commit and the commit to check out. Write them to the working copy.
> - Write the commit being checked out to `HEAD`.
>     If the head is being detached, the commit hash is written directly to the `HEAD` file.
>     If the head is not being detached, the branch being checked out is written to `HEAD`.
> - Set the index to the contents of the commit being checked out.
> - Report the result of the checkout.

Again, it is a simplification (compared to the actual Git code), but gives a good idea on how a checkout is supposed to work.

For more, you can listen the [**GitMinutes #31: Mary Rose Cook on Gitlet**](http://episodes.gitminutes.com/2015/02/gitminutes-31-mary-rose-cook-on-gitlet.html) podcast episode by Thomas Ferris Nicolaisen.