# Tool-oriented tutorial for git?

Tags: git, version-control

Im sure there are plenty of threads asking for git tutorials but I want a very specific tutorial (if there even is one :P).

There are many tutorials who focus on **how to do this and that** using git. They just give you some ready-made recipes for performing specific tasks. Which is great... if you want to do exactly that and nothing else/more/different.

I, on the other hand, have always preferred the tool-oriented approach (if I may call it that): a tutorial which descripes each tool/part/functionality of some technology, says exactly **what it does, how it works** and most importantly - **what are all possibilites**. Because if I know exactly what tools I have and how to use them, I can figure out on my own how to perform specific tasks. And, whenever I have special case - I can adjust and I know how to do it.

Git manual is exactly in that spirit, however it lacks the big picture - it doesn't explain more general terms like repositories, branches, git's overall approach to version control and so on...

So - do you know any tutorials written in the tool-oriented (rather than *how-do-I-do-this*) spirit? With explanation of all the general concepts as well, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't explain more general terms like repositories, branches, git's overall approach to version control

That would be covered by the [**Pro Git** book v2](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

> do you know any tutorials written in the tool-oriented (rather than how-do-I-do-this)

- chapter 9: [Git Internals](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals)
- [Git Internals](https://github.com/blog/1640-git-internals-pdf-open-sourced)
- [Main Git features implemented and annotated in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28187897/6309).

Answer (score 0):

while git provides a beautiful documentation as well
takes you from basics to a higher level of flow
https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

The following link will really help you to figure out physically what is the concept and very beautifully illustrated with pictorial presentation of each event you do.
http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but my team recently published a guidebook that teaches coders how Git works from a code perspective - i.e. how Git's code actually works, instead of a manual on how to use Git's commands. If you are interested you can check it out [here](https://initialcommit.io/#baby-git).