# What affects Git checkout time?

Tags: git

I have small repository and a large repository (containing lots of binaries).

Now when I checkout branches in the small repository the working directory is switched to the new content in an instant.

Now in the large repository it can take up to 10-15 seconds. My theory is that in the latter case it takes time for git to:

1. Delete current working directory
2. Extract the new working directory from the internal git DB - basically meaning decompressing a lot of binaries.

But I have not found any documentation backing this up? What determines the local checkout time, is it as simple as stated above?

Comment: This is the matter of git performance itself. Joshua Redstone wrote this [letter](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/189776) a while ago about git performance. This is his colleague wrote [this post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3549679) about reasons why it happens

Comment: Hm not really a clear/simple answer for this specific git operation, but maybe it's not simple to answer what is taking the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The more the number of changes, longer the `git checkout` operation takes.

Yes. From an external viewpoint, it **IS** as simple as that.

For a better understanding of the internals, start by taking a look at this [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28187897/319204) for a summary of the internal procedure followed by `git checkout`.

---

To be more pedantic and start digging deeper, here is a profile of a "typical" `git checkout` involving 10,000 files that took about 7s (switching branches within a local Linux-kernel git repository) :

```
time strace -c git checkout master  > git-checkout-strace.txt
Checking out files: 100% (10651/10651), done.
Switched to branch 'master'
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 27.21    0.067416           4     18336           write
 25.83    0.063994           6     10229         7 unlink
 14.88    0.036865           3     11182      1775 open
  8.28    0.020507           2     12136       689 lstat
  7.97    0.019744        6581         3         1 futex
  5.53    0.013699           1      9409           close
  5.21    0.012910           1      8913           fstat
  2.96    0.007327          15       480       273 rmdir
  ...
  ...
  ...
(skipping the rest of  long list that accounts for the remaining 1% time)
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.247793                 71970      2767 total

real    0m7.148s
user    0m2.606s
sys     0m4.137s
```

**Some interesting facts:**

1. The most time-consuming system calls are `open()`, `write()` and `unlink()`.
   Combined together they account for 2/3rds of the time spent in system calls.
2. Only 0.24s ( out of a total 7.14s) were actually spent in system calls.
3. Also running `git checkout` under `strace -r` will show time-intervals between any 2 consecutive system calls.

Run `strace -r git checkout master  > git-checkout-strace-intervals.txt`
 followed by `awk '{print $1}' git-checkout-strace-relative-timestamps.txt | sort`
to find large intervals between system-calls at the end of the sorted list.

```
0.000167 rename(".git/index.lock", ".git/index") = 0
0.462548 brk(0x38ac000)            = 0x38ac000
```

The above snippet indicates that git was busy doing something for almost half a second (0.462548s to be exact) after renaming `index.lock` but before it decided to request some more memory (`malloc()` --> `brk`)

On a typical `git checkout` run you will find half a dozen such instances when git appears to be busy in userspace without issuing any system calls. **Make a note of them for further inspection**.

Once you are comfortable with this level of understanding,
next proceed to take a look at the **[actual implementation of `git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/checkout.c)**.

Armed with the knowledge of where exactly git stalled during execution you can simply look for the implementation surrounding the instances above that were **noted down for further inspection** to know more about what git was doing.